# iOS 7 UIImagePickerController status bar trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

In app everything goes okey until opening UIImagePicker and choosing picture, or just tapping Cancel.

Before opening picker view looks nice.
[image]

But when you close picker status bar overlaps view
[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Do you do any view positioning in `viewWillAppear:`? If yes, that could be the problem, since viewWillAppear gets called when you dismiss a modal view controller (like an image picker).

Comment: no positioning at viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

You can check status bar height with `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height`; 20 ist standard height, 40 is double height like for "enabled hotspot" or "background call". Then readjust the view position manually.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem when not using a Navigation Controller and calling the Image Picker. And another time when using custom Status Bar.

Here is a great tutorial on the best way to setup status bar.

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/